# .htaccess redirect to subdomain on port 8000 without changing URL?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

We have a map application hosted on a subdomain of our site which we want to be able to access from the URL http://www.example.com/map/

The problem is that the subdomain is hosted on a different server, and the map application is on port 8000.

Is there any way to redirect to the map application from `/map/` on our main domain, without the URL changing, using either .htaccess or PHP?

Also, I don't have access to the server the map application is hosted on.

Comment: You can always use an iframe if everything else fails.

Comment: This is what reverse proxys are for.

Answer (score 3):

Using mod_proxy, in your vhost/server config for `www.example.com`

```
ProxyPass /map http://subdomain:8000/
ProxyPassReverse /map http://subdomain:8000/
```

Using mod_rewrite to hand off to mod_proxy, in your vhost/server *or* htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?map/(.*)$ http://subdomain:8000/ [L,P]
ProxyPassReverse /map http://subdomain:8000/
```